# In Memoriam: Mr. Oreo

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[**Mr. Oreo**](https://www.facebook.com/quintalayla/posts/1862813517160687), who was the model for Rocket Raccoon [has passed away at the age of 10](https://twitter.com/getFANDOM/status/1093603103377580032).

[image: Image of Mr. Oreo, the Raccoon]

Comment: Is this our first [in-memoriam] for a non-human life form?

Comment: @Randal'Thor out of the non-deleted ones, it would seem so.

Comment: @Jenayah It'll be aliens next. Aliens I tells ya.

Comment: @Randal'Thor oh, yes, the _Alien_ franchise is pretty much dead indeed.

Comment: At the risk of sounding callous, I hope he finished filming all his scenes for *Avengers: Endgame*.

Comment: Tsk tsk tsk, you callous fool, @Paul!

Answer (score 20):

A Ravager Funeral is befitting for him:

[image: Ravager Funeral scene from Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol.2]

Answer (score 2):

This rac was big good. See you in rac heaven.